# Why does this code result in a core dump?

Tags: linux, c

I have this piece of C code below and whatever value I give to `code[]`, I'm getting `Segmentation fault (core dump)`. Do you have any ideas why this happens?

```
char code[] = "";
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int (*func)();  
  func = (int (*)()) code;  //typecast the array code to be a function pointer
  (int)(*func)();   
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to work and what is the intended result?

Comment: i use this code  to test some shellcode  examples

Comment: What happens in your example is that you are trying to interpret program data as machine instructions. Not only aren't there any valid instructions there, but the data region probably has a no-execute flag set so the OS kills your process as soon as you jump to that address.

Comment: for example i try to print a hello message in terminal (char code[] = "\xeb\x19\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\x31\xc9\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\x59\xb2\x05\xcd"\
              "\x80\x31\xc0\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe2\xff\xff\xff\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f";)

Answer (score 1):

Converting an [object](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15p1) pointer to a function pointer is [*undefined behaviour*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3). Simply put, a function pointer may only be converted to another function pointer, but not to an object pointer or vice versa.

Note that modern OSes protect data memory segments against execution of code by default ("no execute", `NX`), so you happily run into access violation exceptions.

Last not least: You very likely have to link/bind/relocate your code to do something useful.